# Angular Updating Parent div Class when Click

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I have the following code and i wish to update the parent class when click on the image. The image will call "SelectVariation" method when clicked. Is there any way to do this?

component.html :

```
<div class="clr-row">
<ng-container *ngFor="let variOption of product.variOptions">
<div class="card clickable clr-col-2 variationCard" 
*ngFor="let variOptionTwo of variOption.variOptionTwos"> //Update this class
  <div class="card-img" (click)="selectVariation(variOptionTwo.id, $event)">
    <clr-tooltip>
      <img src="{{variOptionTwo.url}}" class="variationImgScale" clrTooltipTrigger>
      <clr-tooltip-content clrPosition="top-right" clrSize="m" *clrIfOpen>
          <span>{{variOption.optName}} - {{variOptionTwo.optName}}</span>
      </clr-tooltip-content>
    </clr-tooltip>
  </div>
</div>
```

component.ts :

```
selectVariation(id: number, event: any) {
  //Update parent class
}
```

Comment: What do you mean? Did you mean that there is a parent component? If that so, please check EventEmitter.

Comment: @iamjc015, sorry i should make my title more specific. What i mean is to update the parent DIV, not parent component. In my component.html, I want to update the parent div which has the class "card clickable" when click on div with "card-img" class.

Answer (score 0):

In the child component use
`@Output() variableHere = new EventEmitter<>();
this.variableHere.emit(this.variableToSend);`

Then in the parent associate the variable to a method in html child template definition: 
`<app-child (variableHere)="manageVariable($event)"></app-achild>`

In the parent component define the method and do a variable equels the result of the method for example:

```
manageVariable(event) {
   this.variableToUpdate = event;
 }
```

If you have to check if the variable has changed his state call what you need to check in an  ngDoCheck().

Comment: Thanks for the answer but sorry i should make my title more specific. What i mean is to update the parent DIV, not parent component. In my component.html, I want to update the parent div which has the class "card clickable" when click on div with "card-img" class.

Comment: Then use ngModel to the div, with the value of the variable

Answer (score 0):

Take the advantage of the `EventEmitter` in angular with `output`

parent.component.html

```
<my-child-comp (onSelectVariation)="myVariation($event)" ></my-child-comp>
```

parent.component.ts

```
myVariation(myVars) {
    console.log(myVars)
}
```

child.component.html

```
<button (click)="onSelectVariation.emit(myData)">trigger variation</button>
```

child.component.ts

```
@Output() onSelectVariation = new EventEmitter();
```

Name which you have defined in the `output` should be used as a event in it host element in parent

Comment: Thanks for the answer but sorry i should make my title more specific. What i mean is to update the parent DIV, not parent component. In my component.html, I want to update the parent div which has the class "card clickable" when click on div with "card-img" class.

Comment: what class you want to add/remove in your parent element?

Comment: I have a CSS class called "selected" which will apply border to the box when clicked.